# File upload working in Visual Studio IIS Express but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I have a view on a web application where a file is uploaded by a user to pre-fill a form. The view on which the form is located has two `Html.BeginForm` declarations, one to upload the file, and one to submit the filled form. Everything works fine when I debug locally using IIS Express, but when I deploy to my development server, the file does not upload. I am hoping someone might be able to provide some insight into why this is occurring.

File upload excerpt from view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Populate", "ScProject", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   //file upload and submit button
}
```

File upload excerpt from controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Populate(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
      try
      {
         string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
         file.SaveAs(path);
         return RedirectToAction("Create", new { file = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName) });
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         ...omitted error logging code...
         return RedirectToAction("Create");
      }
   else
   {
      ...omitted error logging code...
      return RedirectToAction("Create");
   }
}
```

The `RedirectToAction("Create", new { file = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName) });` reloads the view and populates the form using the uploaded file. I have attempted to execute this action using a pre-uploaded file by entering a url: `../ScProject/Create?file=upload.pptx` which again, works fine on IIS Express, but fails on the development server. If anyone can offer any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you say failing,are you seeing any error or just does not save file on server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the check list:

1. Do you use Windows authentication on the failing server?
2. Are you running Application pull under service account or ApplicationPoolIdentity?
3. Does your target folder security allows Read/Right access to that account?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is saving file when run in IIS Express but not IIS then its mostly issue with App Pool Identity does not have permissions to access the directory on which you are trying to save the file.